# Do most differential equations not have an analytic solution?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, galois-theory

It is often said that most differential equations (with a solution) do not have an analytic solution, i.e. expressible as a finite combination of elementary functions. Is this proven?

A more formal statement would be: Given the set $S$ of all ODEs that are a finite combination of elementary functions (of fixed order, if that makes the proof simple), the set of ODEs with analytic solution $A$ is smaller than $S$.

How would one measure size in this case? Can $A$ be a dense subset of $S$ in some topology? $A$ could have measure zero and $S$ measure one?

Comment: In my opinion most DE's don't have a solution. -:)

Comment: Here "most" isn't literal. The number of finite strings of a finite alphabet of symbols is $\aleph_0$. Obviously, there are an infinite number of ODE with solutions and without solutions.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, I'm sure by whatever measure we employ the set of ODE with analytic solutions is measure 0 compared to the set of all possible ODE (which we of course have to restrict to $F(x,f(x),f'(x),\dots,f^{(n)}(x))=0$ where $F$ is a combination of elementary functions).

Comment: @YuriyS, how you define a *meaningful* measure in the set of "acceptable" strings beyond the counting measure?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, you are right. From my understanding, both sets are countable, which makes my previous comment false

Comment: Only a clarification: differential equations do not form a set but more appropriately a category.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, interesting. Some link?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla many works of Krasil'shchik, Lychagin and Vinogradov and their pupils deal with this aspect, especially (but not exclusively) for PDE, exactly with the aim of determine the structure of exact solutions: I own their "Geometry of Jet Spaces and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations", Gordon and Breach (1986), even if I must admit that, in the more technical part, it is not an easy read.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, thanks. Some day maybe...

Answer (score 2):

The problem of the symbolic integrability of functions is settled by the [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)). The modern developments related to this theory les to the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), which is used in the CAS for automatic intergation.

Some ODE's are solved by one or more ordinary integrations (f.i. first order linear equations with non-constant coefficients), and Liouville's theorem applies. For others, maybe the theorem can be generalized. I wouldn't believe that they are "easier".

---

Also think that ordinary equations are a trivial case of ODE's, and I don't think we even have a theory of solvability in the non-linear case.

E.g. $$ye^y=x$$ doesn't have an analytical solution in $y$, while $$3e^{3y}+e^y=x$$ does.

Comment: I know that Liouville theorem and differential Galois theorem exist. Unfortunately, they are way beyond my reach and I have no idea how to apply them to the problem at hand.

Comment: @jinawee: do you expect that an easy solution will come to you by magic ?

Comment: No, but I expected a less condescending comment.

Comment: @jinawee: why do you ask the question if you know the answer ?

Comment: I know that the answer is not trivial, but I don't know the answer. I hoped that someone knew the answer. I think a simpler question would be a better starting point. Like are "most" fifth degree equations not solvable by radicals?